# Vs 2015: ReSharper 10.0.1 File Layout doesn't get applied

Tags: c#, resharper

We used to arrange our Files with a Tool called NArrange.

Unfortunately, this doesn't get advanced anymore and thus doesn't work with the new C#-Expressions like String-Interpolation etc.
I'd like to use ReSharper for the arrangement and also tried to work trough the instructions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/File_and_Type_Layout.html?origin=old_help

From what I've seen in them and in the VS, there is a default Template for every Type and the "Full Cleanup" should apply it.

But just nothing happens.

I also tried to change some stuff on the Default Layout and created my own Profile as suggested, but it keeps happening nothing.

Since I can't get any information from Mr. Google, I guess I'm doing something wrong, which is pretty obvious?

Comment: When changing Layout Options, go via **Resharper.Options** rather than **Resharper.Manage Options** otherwise you run the risk of applying the changes to a profile which may not be active

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I always navigate trough Manage --> Options. I also checked, if the "Apply file Layout" is set in my Profile, which is the case.

Comment: No worries.  I say so cause I got hit with this once and it nearly drove me batty ;)   Maybe ask JetBrains?  They are generally pretty quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: ReSharper can't make use of other Regions than the ones defined in the File Layout: As soon as a to ReSharper unknown Region is in the File, it seems to stop the whole process and just does nothing.